# SP2013 search - Is there a way to force the crawling of an item in the next incremental crawl?

Tags: 2013, search, crawling

I'm considering using the new "Content Enrichment web service" possibility in SP2013 in order to populate a custom managed property when crawling an item in a SPList (more details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163982(v=office.15).aspx).

I would need, however, to update the value of the managed property in certain circumstances, for all items in a given list (also on all lists in a given SPWeb).

Is there a way to programmaticaly mark an item (or preferably an entire list or even SPWeb) so that it is re-indexed in the next incremental crawl?

Answer (score 2):

Under List Settings - Advanced settings there is a "Reindex" button you could use. I guess you could set this flag programmatically as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to mark files for re-crawling here is an example method, hope it helps

```
public void ReCrawlDocument(string searchServiceName, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchServiceName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                SearchServiceApplication app = SearchService.Service.SearchServiceApplications.FirstOrDefault(ss => ss.Name.ToLower() == searchServiceName.ToLower());
                CrawlLog cLog = new CrawlLog(app);

                cLog.RecrawlDocument(path.TrimEnd('/'));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

the SearchServiceApplication and CrawlLog classes are found in Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration namespace

Also the process executing this method needs to be 64bit and needs SharePoint admin account

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 to the rescue. 2013 has a new feature called ["Continuous crawl"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802%28v=office.15%29.aspx), this will do what you want it to do, as it keeps the content very fresh and updated in the index.

You don't need to worry about fine tuning it for such things, it will handle it, itself.

Comment: So, to clarify, there is no possibility to push content to crawl. Instead MS created continuous craws.

Comment: Oh, I guess there's some misunderstanding here. I want to use the "Content enrichment" functionality, so I will have a managed metadata which is not mapped to any crawled property of a list item - it is filled out programmatically. The property is filled out at crawl time. The issue is how to update, later on, the value of such managed property.